# LiveCode 6 XML library function use

Tags: livecode

LiveCode 6.x has an XML library with a function revCreateXMLTreeFromFile. When I try to use it, it compiles, but on execution I get a "can't find handler" error. Is there a trick to using the XML library? Or is this a LiveCode bug?

Comment: Could you please post the code snippet you are using?

Comment: Also tell us the text of the error message. When you say it compiles, do you mean the script editor accepts your script, or that you are building a standalone? The right answer will depend on which environment the error occurs in. Since you are seeing the error message, I assume you are still running inside the LiveCode IDE.

Comment: @Jacque S/He writes he gets a "Can't find handler" error.

Comment: Right, I should have said "the full error text". The hint would help to see if there is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making an app for iOS/Android or for a desktop OS?

You need to make sure that you include the XML external in the standalone. You do this in the standalone settings.

My book [Programming LiveCode for the Real Beginner](http://livecodebeginner.economy-x-talk.com/) contains two sections on using XML.